# ServerXMLHTTP fails on unresolvable ul

Tags: xmlhttprequest, msxml, navision, dynamics-nav, serverxmlhttp

We are using the MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60Class to make HTTP requests. Usually this works fine, but on some occasions when the url cannot be resolved, the  **send** method fails. In this case an exception is thrown.

The problem is that we program in Microsoft Dynamcs NAV C/AL code. This language does not support error trapping (try catch).

Does anybody know if there is some setting in the ServerXMLHTTP60Class that prevents the **send** method from failing?

Note: the send method fails, so checking the response status is not an option.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Depend your on version of Nav you have different ways to handle exeptions.

In Nav 2016 there will be [try function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn951443(v=nav.90).aspx)

In previous versions you should use `if codeunit.run then` syntax to catch the exception and `getlasterrortext` to get error message.

For more information read [Vjeco](http://vjeko.com/try-catch-in-cal)

Another option to avoid unhandled exceptions is to write a [wrapper class](http://techblog.byllemos.com/2008/10/writing-an-automation-for-navision-in-c/) around ServerXMLHTTP60Class that will catch all exceptions and handle them in the way you like.

Comment: Hi Mak, thanks for your reply! We will be using the RUN option (2009R2), but was kinda hoping for a non 'crashing' automation property.

Comment: @Roeland if you really want this then write wrapper for ServerXMLHTTP60Class that will cath all exeptions and throw none.

Comment: Hi, I agree, the is no way to catch the error messages or handle exceptions in 2009